# Implement JWT with devise or other user managment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, jwt

I want use `json web token` in my new project. In this project, I use `angularjs` and `ruby on rails` in this project.

Now I want use `jwt` in project. Before I use `devise` for user management in back end server, but now I don't know is true that I use `devise` with `jwt` or not. By information that I find, **`devise` is work by `session`**, **and one of the perpose of `jwt` is remove the session.**

Question: Is it correct to use `devise` with `jwt` or I have to write a simple user management instead of devise and just save user information (email and password) on database?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the example that @pankas mentioned. You can see a screencast walkthrough here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CAq-F2icp4

In my example, we bypass the standard session management provided by devise and simply check the validity of the JWT. Now, why would you still use devise? Well you certainly don't have to. However, using devise you get a lot of other benefits for free right out of the box - mainly you get a reliable platform to handle user registration and authorization. That's why I worked to build a solution that integrated the two. I still use devise for everything else aside from the session management and that was reason enough to perform the integration. I hope this helps.